# how to convert [Any] to NSArray?

Tags: swift

[image: warning when as! NSArray]

how to convert `[Any]` Array to `NSArray`, because I want to use "reverseObjectEnumerator" just in NSArray!

Comment: Why are you using NSArray o.0

Comment: I can't sure that [Any].reversed is equal to [NSArray reverseObjectEnumerator]. My OC code is using [NSArray reverseObjectEnumerator], I just want to translate it to swift.

Comment: Don't write Objective C in Swift syntax. It never works out well. They're completely different languages, with different styles, idioms and tools.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! After translate some files, i feel very bored!
Anyway ,thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you converting `[Any]` to `NSArray` when you can use `reversed()` with your `[Any]`? In Swift it's better to use a native Array instead of `NSArray`.

```
for item in keysStoreBySize.reversed() {

}
```

If you still want to use `NSArray` then you can use the `NSArray` initializer [`init(array:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1412169-init).

```
let array = NSArray(array: keysStoreBySize) //Will convert [Any] to NSArray
```

Comment: Thx, OC:
    NSArray *keysSortedBySize = [mainSizes keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
for (NSString *key in [keysSortedBySize reverseObjectEnumerator]) {}
Does [Any].reversed is equal to [keysSortedBySize reverseObjectEnumerator]
i just want translate to swift.

Comment: I change it to:    
 let keysSortedBySize = mainSizes?.keysSortedByValue(using: #selector(NSNumber.compare(_:)))
  let arr = NSArray.init(array: keysSortedBySize!)
    
for key  in arr.reverseObjectEnumerator() {}